# A bit of joined mesh remains unaffected by the Armature!

Tags: mesh, armature, unity

I have a character that I'm importing into Unity. The Hair and Head are separate meshes that I joined into one mesh, and are part of an Armature. The Head enters the "Pose Position" when I enter Edit mode, but the Hair doesn't move. When I import the character into Unity, the hair is bouncing all around as a separate unit. They are one mesh and are supposed to move as one solid unit! How can I fix this? I'm so confused.
[image: Gif example]

Comment: You have to assign wheights. You can use the automatic assign tool, Weight Paint mode, or assign the vertex groups in Edit mode in the properties panel.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/index.html

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/skinning/parenting.html#with-automatic-weights

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html